# unable to extract data from all nodes of a page

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to extract the data from the [this link](http://www.nykaa.com/republic-day-beauty-sale-online?root=hdr_sale)

the code I am using is:

```
$mydoc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

$my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="free-offers"]/div[@class="center"]' );


foreach( $nodes as $node )
{        
    //echo "entered";

    $urlnode=$node->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $url=$urlnode->item(0)->getAttribute('href');

    $imgTags = $node->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $img = $imgTags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $title=$imgTags->item(0)->getAttribute('alt');
    echo $tile.",".$img.",".$url."<br>";
}
```

But with this, I am able to extract only the first `div` node, not the rest. Can anyone point out the mistake I am doing in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `xpath` is not correct, it is only getting the parent `div`. I think you want this:

```
'//div[@class="free-offers"]/div[@class="center"]/div'
```

Comment: it gives me an error Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object on the href line

Comment: my ba one of the links had the a tag missing addd a check and it works,